# How to control a combo box by using another combo box in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have 4 combo box in my HTML form. First 2 are Area and Subarea. Another 2 are Type and Subtype. I want to fill combo box using database values. I already filled first combo box i.e. Area ID but after that when I select particular Area then according to that value I want to fill SubArea combo box. I can't do it in PHP only. And I am new to JavaScript and Ajax. Will you please help me??

Comment: Post the code you have so far.

Comment: Use the selectedvaluedchanged event

Comment: Ajax to call the php file, with the success data, populate the combobox.

Comment: can you paste your code?

Answer (score 1):

Many people have in fact tackled this problem before. It is frequently refered to as a "dependent" or "related" or "cascading" selectbox/combobox. Here's a google search to get you some plugins for javascript (using the excellent [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/)): https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=jquery+dependent+select&oq=jquery+dependent+select

Also, the "related questions" on the right side of this question look fairly pertinent to your situation, try reading up on some of them.

Please note that the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) encourages questions to match one or all of the criteria

- a specific programming problem
- a software algorithm software tools
- commonly used by programmers practical, answerable problems that are
- unique to the programming profession

Which, as mustafa.0x points out, your question is overly broad and does not include a specific question. Take a swing at using a plugin, or research some non-jQuery solutions, and if you run into trouble, post another question with the specific problem you're running into.

Answer (score 0):

I use an event in javascript then I can retrieve the id being use from it but sadly cannot import it to php.

`
* Department Name

```
<select name = "dept_type" id = 'new_jobdep_id' onchange = 'clickSelect(this.value)' class= "form-control" required>
       <option value = "" selected>-----Select Department---</option>

     <?php 

           $sql_in = mysql_query('Select * from department where DeptStatus = 1');


                while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_in)){
                     $depID = $r['DeptID'];
                     $depName = $r['DeptName'];

                    $depName = ucwords($depName);


        ?>
               <option value = <?php echo $depID; ?>  required><?php echo $depName; ?> </option>
         <?php
                }
        ?>
  </select>`
```

hopefully this code can give you a good logic.

Pls.. answer this question.. 
I just want to get the value the select statement below then make it as a reference to another combo box by inserting the retrieve ID from php to my query..

Answer (score -1):

This is a broad design question, but you'll need to attach an event to the combo box, so when an item is selected, you execute an AJAX request which retrieves the sub-items of the selected item.